# Every blessing begins baruch attah adonai elohany melech ha'olam. Why?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, provenance, malchut-royalty

For the past half-century, every blessing I have recited has begun with " baruch attah adonai elohany melech ha'olam".  Why is this so?  When was the phrase created?  Was there some rationale behind it?  Why is G-d described as a king (Melech)?

Comment: I can think of a number of prayers that don't begin with that phrase.

Comment: In light of DoubleAA's comment, (which is more than just stating his opinion, even if it seems to be phrased that way), I think you should edit your question to narrow what type of blessings you mean. I assume you mean "birkot hanehenin" - blessings said before "enjoying" things, such as those made on foods. There, I think all of them start the way that you described.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that *you know that it is allowed to bless in any language* and you ask for the meaning of each one of the criteria. You ask for blessing pattern. 
 1. for need to say **Ata**,   2. to say **Name**,   3. and to say **Kingdom**. In Gemara and poskim, we see that the precise words are not the point. We can find **3 rules** in Talmud:  **(1)** To change a blessing from the pattern elaborated by Chachamim makes it non valuable;  **(2)** Rav said that one of the criterion is to remember the name of G-d. **(3)** Rabbi Yochanan said that one of the criterion is to remember the kingdom of G-d.

For criteria: Brachot 40b:

> Pattern:
>   ר' יוסי אומר כל המשנה ממטבע שטבעו חכמים בברכות לא יצא ידי חובתו
>
> Name:
>   והאמר רב כל ברכה שאין בה הזכרת השם אינה ברכה
>
> Kingdom:
>   ורבי יוחנן אמר כל ברכה שאין בה מלכות אינה ברכה
>
> Abaye ruled as Rav.

**Tosfot** (paragraph starting by "Amar Abaye") said that **Rif** ruled as Rabbi Yochanan, (***Taz*** 214 Sayif Katan 1, said, after reading poskim that **Rabbi Yochanan adds to the rule of Rav**: not Name only, but also kingdom would be said). **Tosfot Brachot 54a** needs the 2nd ant 3rd criteria both and quotes a Talmud Yerushalmi, and extend the rule to Brachot for thunder and similar events and situations cited in the 9st Chapter of Brachot (some Rishonim and Acharonim don't agree):

> הרואה וכו' אומר ברוך שעשה נסים לאבותינו וכו'. פירש רבי' שמעיה דכל הני ברכות צריכות להזכרת שם ומלכות **ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם** וכן כתב רבינו שמשון מקוצי כי הר''י היה רגיל לברך על הברקים ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם שכחו וגבורתו מלא עולם וכן פר''י **ומייתי ירושלמי דפירקין רבי זעירא כו' כל ברכה שאין בה וכו'** :‏

Yerushalmi Brachot 62a (chapter 9 , halacha 1), Name + Kingdom + Ata:

> רבי זעירא ורבי יהודא בשם רב **כל ברכה שאין עמה מלכות אינה ברכה** אמר רבי תנחומא אנא אמר טעמא (תהילים קמה) ארוממך אלהי המלך.  **רב אמר צריך לומר אתה** ושמואל אמר אינו צריך לומר אתה.

The Halacha is ruled as above by Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chayim 214](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1044): Name --> yes; Kingdom --> yes; Ata --> mentioned in Yerushalmi. The criteria are learned from verses: You can find the Drashot in Bavli and Yerushalmi Above cited, . The [Abudarham](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=18&hilite=) adds citations from Midrash. The name is an attribute and the kingdom too. They must be mentalized, the scope is to be aware of G-d from our experience.